# IOS tests interacting with Mac file system

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xctestcase

So I'm playing around with swiftui XCTestCase. I have a bunch of tests that run and get that they are running in the simulator or on the device.

However - I now have a need to interact with the Mac I'm on - ie read and write to the Mac file system from the IOS tests - is it possible - as the test is running in the simulator.

Comment: What are your specific use cases that require accessing the Mac filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XCTestCase` has access to the local file system be design with some restrictions. For example:

```swift
func testExample() throws {
    print("\(Bundle.allBundles)")
    print("\(Bundle(for: type(of: self)))")
}
```

This code will produce something like this:

```sh
[NSBundle </Volumes/Extended/Archive/Xcode_11.6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreGlyphs.bundle> (not yet loaded), NSBundle </Users/dive/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9CDF771B-204F-45B9-AAC3-6036AB7B117D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5DE85255-F202-4BAB-871A-7C20C2DB37D9/TestingBundles.app> (loaded), NSBundle </Users/dive/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9CDF771B-204F-45B9-AAC3-6036AB7B117D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5DE85255-F202-4BAB-871A-7C20C2DB37D9/TestingBundles.app/Frameworks> (not yet loaded), NSBundle </Users/dive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestingBundles-exdmnsfatmhbztarzgjvvlwwpoan/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestingBundles.app/PlugIns/TestingBundlesTests.xctest> (loaded)]

NSBundle </Users/dive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestingBundles-exdmnsfatmhbztarzgjvvlwwpoan/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestingBundles.app/PlugIns/TestingBundlesTests.xctest> (loaded)
```

As you can see, these paths are related to the DerivedData directory. As a result, you cannot use relative paths to the directory with your project or tests.

Also, you can use `FileManager` directly. It inherits the same environment and has access to the local file-system as well. For example:

```swift
func testExample() throws {
    let manager = FileManager.default
    print(try manager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: ("~/" as NSString).expandingTildeInPath))
}
```

It will produce something like this:

```sh
/Users/USER_NAME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9CDF771B-204F-45B9-AAC3-6036AB7B117D/data/Containers/Data/Application/0D16C376-80A6-4DAE-B435-2FEF7F08A83A
```

Note, that because of the environment, it points to the home directory of the user within a simulator.

As a workaround, we are using a Shared user directory to share such data. There is a "Run Script" in the Test Pre-Actions that copies it:

[image]

Then we access it from `XCTestCase` like this:

```swift
try manager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "/Users/Shared/TestData")
```

It is not ideal and, perhaps, there are some other solutions. But it works fine and has a predictable behaviour.